# What are some ways to optimize a service running on Android?

Tags: java, android, optimization, android-service

I'm wondering what you can do programmatically to minimize the footprint that your service will have on a device?  Are there any particular tricks to the way that you write a service so that it doesn't take up much system memory?  I guess low memory footprint is my main concern so that a user does not want to turn the service off and is willing to have it always running.

****EDIT****

Okay so reading the answers I"m thinking that I must be doing this wrong.  I am using the AlarmManager to periodically wake the service up but I am not ever stopping the service unless the user indicates via the main activity.  So should I include at the end of my onStartCommand after my service performs what it needs to should I call stopService?  Doesn't stop service call onDestroy because if it does I was deregistering my AlarmManager in onDestroy.

The way that it runs right now when I go to running services on my phone it has the service running but it is not actually doing anything until the AlarmManager goes off at which point it performs it's small function and that's it.

Comment: Does it need to be running all the time? Can you use the AlarmManager or listen to Broadcast to start the service only when it is necessary? What are your service for?

Comment: There are so few cases where an "always running" service is needed that it is not even funny. Services either are tasks as @alextsc indicates, or are things users start and stop for foreground stuff (e.g., music players). Unless you can convince us that there is a clear technical reason why your service needs to be "always running", I suggest that you avoid that.

Comment: I edited my original question to address the comments and answers so far.

Comment: Also, aren't there some services that are "continuously" running for Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess low memory footprint is my main concern so that a user does not want to turn the service off and is willing to have it always running.

Theres a huge one for optimization. Androids services are not meant to run all the time (like Windows services or unix daemons).
They are more like a task solver, e.g. download a file. After finished with their task, they should call Service.stopSelf().
If your app needs the service again, it should restart it then for the appropriate task.

Comment: I edited my original question to address the comments and answers so far.

Comment: Response to edit: Hey, basically what you do is the right direction. Starting the service on a regular basis via the AlarmManager is fine. After the service finished his task, you should call stopSelf() inside onStartCommand(). This will call onDestroy(), where you just can do some cleanup (if you need to). If the user should be able to disable the regular starts of the service like you describe, just remove the pending Intent from the AlarmManager when the user clicks the relevant control (e.g. a button).

Comment: Okay so when I call stopSelf would I want to destroy the AlarmManager notification that I set up?  So basically I would only remove the pendingWebsiteIntent from the AlarmManager when the user indicates that they are no longer interested in the service being woken up?  Otherwise after the end of onStartCommand I would just call stopSelf and not cancel the Alarm?

Comment: Usually you dont want to kill the pending Intent inside the service. You just stop the service. If the service should be woken up again or not should be handled outside of it. I dont know what you are trying to do exactly. For example: If you are checking mails every few minutes, you want your service called on a regular basis. You only want to disable the pending Intent when the user disables his mail-account explicitly in the app (=outside of the service).

Comment: Okay I think my problem is that I have been creating the following inside of my Service:  AlarmManager, NotificationManager, and PendingIntent.  I should probably create the AlarmManager inside of my main activity and then it can be destroyed there in the activity at the user command and leave inside the Service class the others and perform my checks etc.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what your service is **doing** so there's really no right or wrong answer. The important thing that I try to stay mindful of is not to keep the service alive for any longer than is required. If your service spends most of its time in an idle state, then consider waking it periodically with an alarm, and stopping the service once its periodic work is complete. This has the added benefit of preventing many task killers from destroying your service if it doesn't stay running for very long.

I also try and use inexact alarm as these are generally kinder on batteries, and battery life is also something that you should be mindful of.

In terms of memory footprint, it is **always** worth freeing up any unused resources, and keeping your code as lean and mean as possible, whether it is in a Service, Activity, Receiver, or anywhere else. Although current smart phones have considerably more memory than feature phones, Android is increasingly being run on comparatively lower spec hardware, so it's worth being mindful of lower end devices.

Reto Meier has recently written some articles which cover these sorts of topics on [his blog](http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/).

Comment: I edited my original question to address the comments and answers so far.